# Altering a thesis after acceptance?

Tags: thesis, errors-erratum

I am told that any changes in content beyond correction of small mistakes, like obvious wrong use of a term or typographics is not allowed. This makes sense to me.

Is this a common opinion or are there institutes somewhere where no chances at all are allowed?

Of course one can ask, why the alterations after acceptance of a thesis. But let's assume perfectionist reasons and in case one wants to show it to potential employers where some mistake might be embarrassing.

Comment: Many theses in my field go through a process in which content is removed or altered and are edited into a form "for public consumption" after acceptance and graduation and then posted on arXiv or are published. This sometimes happens years after the student has graduated. For the "official" copy, you need to follow the "official" rules but what you do with this content after you graduate is your  prerogative.

Answer (score 4):

When I submitted my MSc thesis, I thought my thesis was perfect (English/vocab/grammar). Now, every time I go back and read a section or chapter, I find some mistakes/things I will never use if I'm to write it now! I'm sure this will always be the case since your writing style/opinion will evolve and change. The point is to try to be better in your current work (thesis, papers etc). I wouldn't bother going back to FIX stuff but rather to see how much I have become better!

Answer (score 2):

> Of course one can ask, why the alterations after acceptance of a thesis. But > let's assume perfectionist reasons and in case one wants to show it
>   to potential employers where some mistake might be embarrassing.

This is actually pretty crucial. You should be aware that it is a possible warning sign (depending on the field). In my field I run away from students that wave their thesis around. It means that they didn't get it: the point of research is to do research and anything beyond minimum post-stapling papers together shows you're focusing on wrong things.

Comment: So, you mean instead of showing the thesis to some possible employer, one should instead show the thesis plus some related papers and additional work? To summarize, it's better to show a bunch of work instead of each single file?